# codeigniter form_open() not working for login page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question and trouble with my code,
I am doing login through codeigniter framework, but having issue with login,
When i enter user\password in login form it again coming back to same login page instead of moving to Home1 class.
My guess is this problem due to  form_open('index.php/welcome/login') in login page form, i am not sure how this works for login,

Below two are my class from controller,

---

```
   public function login() //this used for login
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
            $this->m_user->user_login();

        }

    public function home1()//this will be redirecting class
    {
        $this->load->view('home1');
    }
```

---

this is model,

```
public function index()
        {
            if(($this->session->userdata('email')!=""))
            {
                $this->welcome();
            }
            else
            {
                $data['title']='Home';
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
        }

function user_login()
     {
            $user_email=$this->input->post('user_email');
            $user_password=md5($this->input->post('user_password'));


          $this->db->where('user_email',$user_email);
          $this->db->where('user_password',$user_password);
          $query=$this->db->get('ca_user');

      if($query->num_rows()>0)
      {
       foreach($query->result() as $rows)
       {
        //add all data to session
        $_userdata = array(
          'user_id'  => $rows->user_id,
          'user_firstname'  => $rows->user_firstname,
          'user_lastname' => $rows->user_lastname,
          'user_email'    => $rows->user_email,
          'logged_in'  => TRUE,
        );

       }
       $this->session->set_userdata($_userdata);
       redirect('home1','refresh');
       return true;
      }
      return false;
      redirect('signup','refresh');
     }
```

and this is login page

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
          <?php echo form_open('index.php/welcome/login'); ?>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input-field form-control user" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('user_email');?>" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-field form-control password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('user_password');?>" />

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" name="submit"><span class="ladda-label">login</span></button>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: try removing `refresh` from redirect on your model.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cant load a view from your model. Usually model is where your logic placed. To the point i will give you basic sample login method in CI using MVC.

Your Model:

```
class Login extends CI_Model
    {
        // validation setting
        public function LoginRules()
        {
            # code...
            $login_user = [
                [
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'Email Adress',
                    'rules' => 'required'
                ],
                [
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'required'
                ]
            ];

            return $this->form_validation->set_rules($login_user);
        }

        // validation method
        public function validate()
        {
            if ($this->LoginRules())
            {
                if ($this->form_validation->run())
                {
                    # code...
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }

        //Check the user data in database    
        public function CheckUser()
        {

            $query = $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))
                ->where('password', $this->input->post('password'))
                ->limit(1)
                ->get('your table name');

            foreach ($query->result() as $result) ;

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                $userData = [
                    'email'    => $pengguna->email,
                    'username' => $pengguna->username,
                    'login'    => TRUE
                ];

                $this->session->set_userdata($userData);

                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        //logout function
        public function destroy()
        {
            $this->session->unset_userdata(
                [
                    'username' => '',
                    'email'    => '',
                    'login'    => FALSE,
                ]
            );

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
        }
    }
```

Then your controller:

```
public function UserLogSuccess()
    {

        if ($this->session->userdata('login') == FALSE)
        {
            //flash msg data for login failure
            $data = [
                'msg' => 'Must login'
            ];

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $data);

            //redirect user back to login form
            redirect('login');
        }
        else
        {
            // give access
            $data = [
                'uname' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                'email' => $this->session->userdata('email')
            ];

            $this->load->view('user/index', $data);
        }
    }
```

And minimal login form:

```
<div>
    <?php
        if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('msg')))
        {
            // you may ignore this
            foreach ($this->session->flashdata('msg') as $key => $message)
            {
                echo $message['access_tanpa_login'];
            }
        }

        echo form_open('login', ['class' => 'form', 'method' => 'POST']);
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
        <?php echo form_error('email', '<span class="error">', '</span>'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
        <?php echo form_error('password', '<span class="error">', '</span>'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="form-button">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Addition : Sample of validate user on controller

```
public function MyLoginProceed()
    {
        if ($this->login->validate())
            {
                //load the validation model 
                if ($this->login->CheckUser())
                {
                    // if TRUE, then redirect
                    redirect('any/where/you/like');
                }
                else
                {
                    // Login Fail, set flash msg here
                    $data = ['msg' => 'Fail'];
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $data);
                    // Redirect back to login
                    redirect('login');
                }
            }
    }
```

Edit til fit your need. This is just basic approach as example, not clean or bullet proof. Learning purpose.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for code, its nice. but when i press submit button, site redirect to http://localhost/mysite/login, instead of user/index page. this seems because form_open contains 'login'?

Comment: Change the `login` on form_open on the view file. So you should `form_open('yourControllerName/YourMethod', ['method' => 'Your form method here', 'class' => 'your class name', and so on and so on])`

Answer (score 0):

what form_open('index.php/welcome/login')  actaully does is that it generates a html form open tag for you .

For eg : form_open('index.php/welcome/login');  will generate
>/index.php/welcome/login"> and if CSRF is set to true it will generate a hidden input containing CSRF cookie code also.

So when your page loads right click on the page and view source and see if the form open html tag is generated or not . If it has generated that means form_open is working.

A suggestion form my side - looking at your code it seems you are not following the model view controller framework properly. Try to just access the database in model and do the redirects in controller . Get the inputs in variables in controller and send them as arguments to models.